# What are `regex grep`, applied to files, equivalents in Golang?

Tags: go

**Problem**

I am now running a regex grep to multiple files in order to get all TODOs, but it takes a couple of minutes before the commands completes:

```
real    5m8.073s
user    0m35.593s
sys     4m17.608s
```

**Aim**

The aim is to get the number of TODOs in no time.

**Attempt**

According to what I have found on the internet, I think that Golang would be a good candidate and I created the following code.

```
func check_for_todo(path string) {
    text := "//\\sTODO\\s\\d"

    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    s := string(b)

    // containsTodo := strings.Contains(s, text)
    containsTodo, _ := regexp.MatchString(text, s)

    if containsTodo {
        numberOfTodos++
        fmt.Println("This file contains a todo:", path)
    }
}
```

**Results**

The query is now twice as fast compared to bash.

```
real    2m17.050s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.015s
```

**Discussion**

I have the feeling that this code could be optimized and is currently devious. I am now looking into channels and goroutines.

Comment: It looks like you already found the equivalent in Go. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the optimizations made by [the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) (a.k.a `ag`). It does a number of optimizations in order to have extremely fast code search.

Another option might be to pre-construct an index so searches are even fast than anything performed in real time. In the `ag` README, [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) is referenced which does this and could work for extremely large code bases.